# $a^a+b^b=c^c$ (are there any solutions over positive integers?)

Tags: number-theory

> Does $a^a+b^b=c^c$ have solutions over positive integers?

I did not try almost anything because I do not know how to handle these kind of questions.

I did not find this question anywhere, just created it so that I have something to calculate and think about, but, unfortunately, I do not know enough of number theory to attack this problem.

Do you have any ideas?

It could be that this is not at all hard, but at this moment I do not have a clever idea.

Comment: Heh heh, it seems pretty hard to me. XD

Comment: @Frpzzd To me also, but someone could come up with nice idea.

Comment: No.  $c^c$ grows too fast.  Clearly $c>a,b$. But even if $a=b=c-1$ we'd have $2\times (c-1)^{c-1}$ on the left which is much less than $c^c$ for $c≥2$.

Comment: See the answer to [Conjecture similar to Fermat's Theorem.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575885/conjecture-similar-to-fermats-theorem).

Comment: Shalom, the point is that the maximum $a$ and $b$ can be is $c-1$, thus the maximum the left hand side can be is $2\times (c-1)^{c-1}$. The right-hand side, though, is $c^c= c\cdot c^{c-1}\geq2\cdot c^{c-1}>2\times (c-1)^{c-1}$.

Comment: @Shalom: The map $n\mapsto n^n$ is increasing on $\Bbb N$, so that would mean the sum $a^a+b^b$ would be even smaller than $2(c-1)^{c-1}$

Comment: @Clayton Understood.

Comment: @lulu What about this one $a^b+b^c=c^a$?

Comment: Well $(a,b,c)=(1,1,2)$ is a solution.

Comment: Worth noting:  most Diophantine equations are too hard to say much about.  Sometimes there are simple ways to exclude solutions, but when those fail it is generally pretty hard to classify solutions.

Comment: @lulu Yes, I know that.

Answer (score 4):

There are no solutions over the positive integers.

Without loss of generality, $a \le b$. Then the left hand side is bounded by $2b^b$; on the other hand, $c > b$ and the right hand side is therefore at least

$$c^c \ge (b + 1)^{b + 1} > b^b \cdot (b + 1) \ge 2 b^b$$

giving a contradiction.